# Using WebViewOnNavigated with custom Renderer [Xamarin forms]

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using a custom WebViewRenderer in my Xamarin Forms android project that looks like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace ClotureSiadForms.Droid.Renderer
{
    internal class HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                Control.Settings.SavePassword = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked that it is well used, however passwords are still not saved. When I write login and password on the webpage, it asks is Google should save them, I press "yes" but next time sign in data is not proposed, what should I check ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the `OnElementChanged` method like below.

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
           
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true ; 
                Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true ;
                Control.Settings.SavePassword = true;
              
            }
        }
```